# How to see ItemControl.ItemsPanel.Template from code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this xaml sample:

```
<ItemsControl MinHeight="150" ItemsSource="{Binding fieldList}" Name="myItemsControl">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas Name="canvasFields" MinHeight="150" Background="White" Margin="10" Height="{Binding HauteurCanvas}"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left"
                            Value="{Binding Column}" />
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"
                            Value="{Binding Row}" />
                        <Setter Property="Width"
                            Value="{Binding Width}" />
                        <Setter Property="Height"
                            Value="{Binding Height}" />
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <c:ControlCustomField MouseLeftButtonDown="ControlCustomField_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="ControlCustomField_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonUp="ControlCustomField_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

And I want to acces `canvasFields` from code behind But I can only see myItemsControl.

So far I tried plenty of stuff.. In code behind, none of those works:

`canvasFields` This is just not seen.

`((Canvas)(myItemsControl.ItemsPanel.Template))` This gives a "cannot convert" error.

`myItemsControl.canvasFields` This is not seen either.

Well, you see the deal.. How can I "see" canvasFields from code behind?

I'm probably missing something really obvious to access it... 
 Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want that for? whatever you're trying to do, you probably need to do it via proper DataBinding, as opposed to procedural code.

Comment: You're probably right. I'll go on this path and give further information of my progress here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access to it! because it's a template. and not a created control.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `FrameworkElement.GetTemplateChild` method, it is intended for that purpose. However, this requires you to subclass the `ItemsControl`, as this method is protected.

If you need to avoid this, then you can traverse the visual tree of `ItemsControl` using the `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild` method analyzing the type and the `Name` property of elements until you find a proper element.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to traverse the visual descendants of the `ItemsControl` and look for a `Panel` meeting either of the following criteria:

```
if (panel.IsItemsHost && panel.TemplatedParent == itemsControl)
    /* You've found the ItemsPanel. */;

var itemsPresenter = panel.TemplatedParent as ItemsPresenter;
if (itemsPresenter != null && itemsPresenter.TemplatedParent == itemsControl)
    /* You've found the ItemsPanel. */;
```

It may not be 100% reliable, but it hasn't failed me yet.